# I want to assign 1 day after checkin date for check out date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have the HTML as follows

```
<div class="booking-date-fields-container col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="dp3">
  <input type="hidden" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dateArrival"   id="dateArrival">
</div>
<div class="booking-date-fields-container col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="dp4">
  <input type="hidden" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" name="dateDeparture" id="dateDeparture">
</div>
```

and following is the JS file content for the above

```
jQuery("#booking-tab-contents .input-daterange").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: new Date(),
    show: true,
    inputs: jQuery('.booking-date-fields-container')
 });

$('#dp3').datepicker().on('click', function (ev) {
    $('#dateArrival').val( $('#dp3').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
});

$('#dp4').datepicker().on('click', function (ev) {
    $('#dateDeparture').val( $('#dp4').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
});
```

I want to make my date-picker in such a way that, when I select arrival date or check in date, the checkout date must be a day after the check-in date

Comment: Off the top of my head you need to... add a change event to the arrival date picker so that when it changes you can use some JavaScript to get the selected date, and then add one day to it, and then use this new date with a set min date method on the checkout datepicker. This comment is just to provide some logical guidance

Comment: Can you please add jQuery and link which you are using

Comment: Did you figure it out? I want the solution too.